# Does adding a new dictionary key-value remove other elements?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using Unity Engine with C#.

Currently, I have a weird issue. Here's the code for my dictionary:

```cs
private Dictionary<int, List<IExplosionDamageGiver>> m_DeployedExplosiveMap = new Dictionary<int, List<IExplosionDamageGiver>>();
```

The key is a unique ID(using Photon's ViewID) and the value is a list of IExplosionDamageGiver objects.

Here's the code for adding the actual value into the dictionary:

```cs
print("Deployer: " + deployerViewID);
print("Contains Deployer: " + m_DeployedExplosiveMap.ContainsKey(deployerViewID));

if (m_DeployedExplosiveMap.ContainsKey(deployerViewID) == false) {
    print("Create List for " + deployerViewID);
    m_DeployedExplosiveMap.Add(deployerViewID, new List<IExplosionDamageGiver>());

    print("Current Keys: " + m_DeployedExplosiveMap.Keys.Count);

    foreach (var item in m_DeployedExplosiveMap) {
        print("Key: " + item.Key + ", Count: " + item.Value.Count);
    }
}
else {
    print("List for " + deployerViewID + " is already exists");
}

m_DeployedExplosiveMap[deployerViewID].Add(damageGiver);
print("Deployed Count: " + m_DeployedExplosiveMap[deployerViewID].Count);
```

If there's no key in the dictionary, create a new key-value pair then use [] to update the value. Value is a list and used List.Add add new item to the list.

Here's the logs trying deployerViewID 2001:

```cs
Deployer: 2001
Contains Deployer: False
Create List for 2001
Current Keys: 1
Key: 2001, Count: 0
Deployed Count: 1
```

Running the same logic with the same deployerViewID 2001 works fine. Dictionary has 1 key, and the value List is keep adding a new element.

However, when the same logic with a different deployerViewID 1003 causes weird results. I expected that the key 1003 didn't exist in the dictionary so created a new key-value pair, and put the object in the just-created List for ID 1003, but it wasn't. Instead, it ERASES the key-value for deployerViewID 2001. It's just gone.

```cs
Deployer: 1003
Contains Deployer: False
Create List for 1003 // -> Works as expected. New int, List pair created.
Current Keys: 1 // WTF? Why dictionary have 1 key? It is supposed to be 2 keys!!
Key: 1003, Count: 0
Deployed Count: 1
```

I used foreach to iterate the dictionary but key 2001 and its value are just gone. Is this how the Dictionary works in C#? I used this method with many different game scripts but none of them had this issue. Only this code has trouble.

Seriously there's no extra code that accesses the dictionary. That's all the code. Is this a glitch or is my knowledge is wrong? Can anyone please explain to me what the heck is going on?

Comment: Sounds like somewhere between your first and second invocation, you replaced the dictionary with a new, empty dictionary. Can you edit your question to show the steps to produce a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem?

Comment: @DMGregory but that's not possible. there's no extra code for accessing the above dictionary at all. there's no code for Remove, Clear, Replace dictionary. That's the actual whole code.

Comment: An easy litmus test for DMGregory's theory would be to check/log the # of keys immediately before the add. Presently, it appears that you are assuming that previous data is present & being overwritten/erased by the 2nd add - if that's true, you should see the expected # of keys. You claim it's impossible that the dictionary isn't being replaced, but it should be equally impossible that the API is uniquely failing just here. The first thing to establish is which impossible thing has happened.

Comment: @Pikalek I just added some extra logs right before the "Add" method and after the second execution the dictionary was just empty(Keys.Count returned 0). But there's no such code accessing the dictionary somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you have more than one instance of the class that has the `m_DeployedExplosiveMap` member variable?

Comment: That sounds consistent with my claim that in your second invocation you're working with a new, empty dictionary. Doesn't sound so impossible now, does it?  It needn't be code changing the dictionary - it could be a different instance, as Adam says, or in between the two invocations the instance was serialized and deserialized, which would replace the dictionary with the default. That's why we need to see a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - so we can examine the whole lifecycle of the class and whatever could happen between these two calls.

Comment: Since id is a photon's ViewID, WHERE are you calling this code? On the server or on the client?